# Where Is Apache's DirectoryIndex file: index.py

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, directoryindex

I feel like this question is pretty easy but I think I'm missing something. I want to understand more about Apache's (?site-enabled, virtual host, directory?). In my Directory I have `DirectoryIndex /cgi-bin/index.py`. Where is this file located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the argument to DirectoryIndex is a relative path like "index.html" and it exists in the directory you're trying to access.

When the argument begins with a slash, the URL is converted to a file by the servers normal configuration -- things like DocumentRoot and ScriptAlias (since you have /cgi-bin/).

You should be able to determine from your Apache config where /cgi-bin/ is mapped to on the filesystem.

Note: this script is not part of httpd from the ASF.